# Are there any female dwarves, and if not, how do they reproduce?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, dwarves

In the *The Hobbit* and *The Lord of the Rings* series, there are many descriptions of dwarves. But there isn't any mention of female dwarves. Are there any in-universe mentions of female dwarves? If there aren't, then how do they reproduce? Is there any explanation from Tolkien?

Comment: Lord of the Rings DID mention female dwarves and their beards.

Comment: This question was discussed on meta: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12252/question-falsely-closed-as-duplicate

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There were dwarf women. One is mentioned by name in Tolkien's work, Dís, the daughter of Thraín II.

From Appendix A of *The Lord of the Rings*:

> Dís was the daughter of Thraín II. She is the only Dwarf-woman named in these histories. It was said by Gimli that there are few dwarf-women, probably no more than a third of the whole people. They seldom walk abroad except at great need. They are in voice and appearance, and in garb if they must go on a journey, so like to the dwarf-men that the eyes and ears of other peoples cannot tell them apart. This has given rise to the foolish opinion among men that there are no dwarf-women, and that the dwarves 'grow out of stone'.

Dwarf-women are not mentioned in the major stories. They were few, and did not go abroad much, so they probably could add very little to the plot.

Comment: I think the mother of two of the Dwarves from the Hobbit is mentioned (if not named) as well.

Comment: @JamesDouglas: That's the same woman: Dís is Thorin's sister and the mother of Fili and Kili.

Comment: @TimPederick Ah thanks! I haven't read it in a while...

Answer (score 1):

In The Two Towers, one of the characters asks the same question to the dwarf master, and he responds by saying that dwarf women look a lot like male dwarfs, even in the beard.

Comment: links to source?

Comment: @user13267 How do you link to a scene in a movie?

Comment: if you can find a page containing transcripts of the relevant dialogue you can link to them

Comment: @user57423 - Like that

Comment: @Valorum And what if such a YouTube video for the part of a movie I refer to does not exist? Am I expected to buy the movie, learn how to use software to create short video extracts, register with a video portal, and upload a video there? Film scholars are not expected to provide videos when they discuss movies. Why should I?

Comment: @user57423 - For me the question is 'do I want to provide the best answer that I can?' That might mean learning to use a simple clipping tool like LiceCap to provide a short gif, searching for a scene on youtube (which is what I did in this case) or at the very least providing a short transcript of the scene and correctly identifying the correct film. As to *why* you should do so, the simple answer is that good, well-referenced answers with clear and visible sources will tend to get more reputation points for being helpful to other users.

Comment: @Valorum In my eyes you're just adding unnecessary fluff. Film scholars and film reviewers manage to discuss movies without linking to movie clips. The best answer is one that provides all the necessary detail. It would have been more than sufficient to write that `In the Two Towers, Gimli speaks about how dwarf women are often confused for males and Legolas adds that this happens because of their beards`. The movie clip adds nothing to that except a distraction from that information and an incentive to go browse YouTube and waste one's time.

Comment: @user57423 - In my opinion that would be a very poor answer because it would require the reader to either take it on trust that your precis of the script is accurate or watch the entire film to find the sequence that you're referring to.

Comment: "*good, well-referenced answers with clear and visible sources will tend to get more reputation points for being helpful to other users*" - or, for those not motivated by imaginary internet points, it's good to add sources because they make the answer **clearly correct**. Anyone on the internet can claim any old stuff, and the only way to tell the right from the rubbish is to verify it at the source. cc @user57423