# What rock songs are playing in the v-club in the pilot episode of Caprica?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, music-identification, caprica

Bear McCreary has composed [the musical score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_of_Caprica) for the *Battlestar Galactica* prequel series *Caprica*, but the published soundtrack doesn't include the punk rock songs playing in the v-club.

What are those songs?

I'm especially interested in the song featuring a female singer we hear when Zoe Graystone visits the club for the second time in the pilot, right after her mother slapped her. The song starts at about [6:35](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pg7TKQG6290&t=6m35s)<sup>NSFW</sup> (YouTube) or [8:15](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x6rltsu?start=495)<sup>NSFW</sup> (Dailymotion) into the episode.

Comment: Just a note on my edit; I noticed that the YouTube link was a recording where the video was played in the bottom right of the screen over a moving overlay animation that filled up the full screen. These techniques are used to get around the YouTube copyright feature; knowing that this video breaches copyright, it is not something we would link to off this site. For what it is worth, that video was a lot harder to hear, compared to the Dailymotion one.

Comment: @Gnemlock Any upload of any part of any tv series to any video sharing site is copyright infringement. The Dailymotion video is uploaded in a mirror-inverted version to avoid automatic detection. Following your logic, you should delete that link from my question as well. However, a "link to source" is strongly encouraged on this site (see e.g. the comments to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/202298/110768)), and since there are no sources I can link to except copyright infringing video uploads, and since I can't expect you all to buy the DVD, I suggest to keep the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Assistant identified the song for me, after Shazam and SoundHound failed. The song is [Freaky](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lrTxV5eMB20) by Cub from their 1996 album *[Box of Hair](https://cubtheband.bandcamp.com/album/box-of-hair)*.